# Express + node.js: very slow serving of a large directory packed as tar

Tags: node.js, express

I've just started playing with web development, and node.js + express helped me get a simple server up quickly on my not-so-powerful embedded system. When trying to serve a 270MB directory as a tarfile, however, the performance is not good at all with my solution.

After getting some help on irc I tried serving the file using fstream and node-tar, like this:

```
fstream.Reader({ type: "Directory" , path: mydir }).pipe(tar.Pack({})).on("error", function(){ res.statusCode = 500; res.end('Unable to create tarball'); }).pipe(res)
```

It works, but it takes ~20 minutes to download the 270MB file to my PC. As an experiment I tried tar'ing the folder on target, and then scp'ed it down to my PC. This took 1m12s + 2m17s,  which makes quite a big difference.

(I tried serving the pre-tar'ed file using node-static, but ran out of memory on my embedded system)

Any idea what could make the express+node.js-solution so slow?

**Update with some benchmarking:**

I suspect that using another webserver would be better for static file serving, but I don't think it can explain the big difference here.

Benchmarking done on a folder resulting in a 64MB tar

**Manual**:
*46 seconds*

```
# on server:
tar -cf foo.rar <folder>  
# on client
scp root@<ip>/path/to/foo.rar .
```

**fstream + node-tar: directly**
*4 min 25 seconds*

```
fstream.Reader({type: "Directory", path: dir}).pipe(tar.Pack({})).on("error", function(){res.statusCode = 500; res.end('Unable to create tarball');}).pipe(res);
```

**fstream + node.tar: first streaming to file, then serving file**
*1 min 11 seconds*

```
fstream.Reader({type: "Directory", path: dir}).pipe(tar.Pack({})).on("error", function(){res.statusCode = 500; res.end('Unable to create tarball');}).pipe(fstream.Writer('/tmp/test.rar').on("close", function() {
    var rs = fs.createReadStream('/tmp/test.rar');
    rs.on('data', function(data) {
        res.write(data);
    });
    rs.on('end', function() {
        res.end();
    });
}));
```

Comment: I recommend you to use separate server like [nginx](http://nginx.org/) to deliver static content. Node.js is not designed for this purpose.

Comment: To localize the problem, try to: 1) Pipe the tar stream to some file writer; 2) Pipe the tar'ed file reader to the response. At least you will see whether it takes 20 minutes to tar the file or to stream it to the client.

Comment: Good idea. Updated question with some benchmarks.